# Sudden appearance of Chinese (?) characters in Word document (on MacOS)

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

Suddenly, after saving, my MS Word document (Word 2011 on MacOS) it contained a lot of Chinese(?) characters (rest of the text is in German).
([Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cemvml6xlv7eefi/weird_characters_in_word.docx?dl=0) to docx file containing first page).

[image]

Later in the document it looks a bit different, now with numeric nonsense.

[image]

The last Autorecovery file is too old and not helpful. Changing the font type also does not change anything. Undoing the last step also has no effect. It know that the number of characters has not changed compared to the intact version.

**What happened and how can this be undone so that the original ca be recovered?**